# How to list folders and scan them

Tags: python, operating-system

What i try to do with python is conceptually simple,

I need to scan n folders, the idea is to enter the first folder, go back and enter in next folder using python

Comment: Please be aware [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `os` module for that.
It has 2 functions you can use:

1. **os.scandir**: Return an iterator of DirEntry objects (may be either file or folder) for given path.
2. **os.walk**: Returns an iterator of 3-tuple in the form (dirpath,
   dirnames, filenames)

I'd usually prefer using **os.walk**, but in your case, **os.scandir** seems appropiate.
Your would do something like this:

```
from os import scandir

ROOT_DIRECTORY = "PATH TO DIRECTORY WHERE ALL THE FOLDERS YOU MENTION LIVE"

folders = scandir(ROOT_DIRECTORY)
for item in folders:
     # security check, in case there're also files in ROOT_DIRECTORY
     if item.is_dir():

         files_in_folder:scandir(item):
         for child in files_in_folder:

              # You say there will only be one file, but add security check too
              if child.is_file:
                  CALL_YOU_SPECIAL_FUNCTION(child)
                  break    # Optional: in case you just want to do this on first file
```

Hope it helps. Any doubt hit me with a comment